# ASP.NET MVC 3 ContentResult Will Not Accept Class That Inherits From Another Class

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, geolocation

This follows another question I asked here: [Find nearby entities with Bing Maps REST control](http://bit.ly/rpYe4x)

In the above question, within the for loop of the function DisplayResults(response), I've added the following code:

```
    var loc = new Array();
    loc[0] = results[i].Longitude;
    loc[1] = results[i].Latitude;

    var address = {
        AddressLine1: results[i].Address,
        City: results[i].City,
        State: results[i].StateOrProvince,
        PostalCode: results[i].PostalCode,
        Latitude: results[i].Latitude,
        Longitude: results[i].Longitude,
        Country: results[i].CountryOrRegion,
        ID: results[i].UniqueId
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AddAddressToCollection",
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(address),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

This above code constructs an address from each address contained in the resulting data set and sends it back to a ContentResult which returns a null as its purpose is to store each address into the back end which is MongoDB. You may wonder why I am taking this approach - the addresses are seed data for MongoDB. The idea is that this is an open source project and I wanted to add some personalization to work with the developer's GeoLocation by giving them a localized set of addresses corresponding to their detected location (that code is all in my previous post).

Here is the ContentResult's code in the HomeController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult AddAddressToCollection(Address address)
    {
        address.GeoInsert(_dbName, ref _repository);
        return null;
    }
```

This code DOES work with the corresponing POST method when my Address class appears like so:

public class Address
    {
        private double _latitude;
        private double _longitude;

```
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public virtual Guid AccountID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public double[] Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return _latitude; }
        set
        {
            Location[1] = value;
            _latitude = value;
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public double Longitude
    {
        get { return _longitude; }
        set
        {
            Location[0] = value;
            _longitude = value;
        }
    }

    public Address()
    {
        Location = new double[2];
    }

    public void GeoInsert(string dbName, ref Repository repository)
    {
        repository.MongoGeoInsert(dbName, this);
    }

    public Dictionary<Address, double> GeoNear(string dbName, ref Repository repository, double maxKilometers, int limitResults)
    {
        return repository.MongoGeoNear<Address>(dbName, this.Latitude, this.Longitude, maxKilometers, limitResults);
    }

}
```

But here's where I'm curious... Although I don't need this now, I initially tried to have all of my classes in my Model to inherit from the same base class to assist with some custom serialization methods I use. When I inherit from such a class ...let's call it BaseClass, the POST no longer works and I get a 500 response from the server...I'm just not clear what the reason is. Here's an example of what I'm talking about (p.s. if you happen to use any of the below code, just a hint that you should figure out how to use a Dictionary for serialization...it's MUCH faster, but people are more familiar with reflection so that's what I'm going with here):

so quickly, for the Address class I would have:

Address : BaseClass

and the constructor would be...

Address : base("Address")
{
   //although base("Address") isn't necessary unless you're using the dictionary
   //serialization method
}

now the BaseClass...

```
public class Serialization
{
    public abstract class BaseObject
    {
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }

        public string ObType { get; private set; }

        public BaseObject() : this("base") { }

        public BaseObject(string obType)
        {
            ObType = obType;
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public virtual BaseObject Parse(XElement xml)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                ElementName attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(ElementName)) as ElementName;
                if (attribute == null) continue;

                object value = null;
                string stringValue = xml.Element(attribute.Name).Value;

                switch (property.PropertyType.Name.ToLower())
                {
                    case "double":
                        {
                            value = double.Parse(stringValue);
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            value = stringValue;
                            break;
                        }
                }

                property.SetValue(this, value, null);
            }

            return this;
        }

    }

    public class Serializer
    {
        public static T Deserialize<T>(XElement xml)
            where T : BaseObject, new()
        {
            BaseObject obj = new T() as BaseObject;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                //populate obj properties...
                obj.Parse(xml);
            }
            return obj as T;
        }
    }
}
```

okay, I think that should be enough info...any ideas what that wouldn't work? Hopefully I am not missing something very obvious here...but I do much more Silverlight than ASP.NET programming so it's entirely possible I am 0:)

Thanks!

Comment: could you open firebug and tell us what error are you getting??

Comment: Yeah it's a pretty standard 500 error: 
POST /Home/AddAddressToCollection
500 Internal Server Error

I'm thinking it has something to do with how the MVC framework processes Content and Action Results because I know the code on the client side is working (since it works when I don't inherit from the BaseClass)

Answer (score 0):

So the first problem here is that your question's scope is *way* too big.

You start by sending an AJAX request to this "black box" server. But then it turns out that you have code for the server, so why do I care about the AJAX request in the first place? Places to start:

1. Are you sure that serialization is working correctly? Do you have a test that proves that your custom serialization base class actually works? (it should be trivial to fake the input) If not, you'll probably get an error.
2. Is the data getting into MongoDB correctly? If not, you may be throwing an exception and get your error. Note that the CSharp driver [has its own serialization](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial). You may be wrecking that.
3. Can you confirm that the same data is getting to the View? Your view may be blowing up b/c you're depending on some field that doesn't correctly exist.

All in all, this problem should be very easy to diagnose with typical unit test coverage. You made one change to one class, so your test suite should be throwing some pretty clear messages, likely one of the three above.

If your test suite did not throw any errors, then you're clearly missing some important tests.

If you don't have any test coverage, now might be a good time to start.

Comment: The serialization code has been thoroughly tested, but I am not using serialization in this example. To clarify, I am adding this class with the foresight that I may want to use serialization down the road, but that is not the problem. I know the code works so I'm pretty sure it's related to the MVC framework throwing an internal error. Along those lines - sure, I didn't account for this error, but if I had a test in place for this error, why would I be asking this question?!

Comment: Gates, in case you are being thrown off by my Mongo code, I wrote a custom set of Mongo operations to simplify using Mongo. I am very familiar with Mongo serialization and this has nothing to do with that. To simplify interoperability and to lighten transport / storage costs, I will often use custom xml/json serializers when passing or storing data about a particular class.